# c issue error is used unitilialized in this function

Tags: c++, c, compilation

i cant fix the problem how do you do that?

i would like to have some ideas from you to fix this error...

the error that shows me is:
 "Warning: 'inicioLista' is used initialialized in this funciton .......

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct registro
{
    int valor;
    struct registro *sig;
};

typedef struct registro _nodo;


_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador)
{
        return (apuntador = NULL);
}


_nodo *insertarEnLista( int numero , _nodo *apuntador )
{
    _nodo *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    registroNuevo = (_nodo *) malloc(sizeof(_nodo));

    if( registroNuevo != NULL )
    {
        registroNuevo -> valor = numero;
        registroNuevo -> sig = NULL;

        if(apuntador != NULL)
                apuntador = registroNuevo;
        else
            apuntadorAuxiliar =  apuntador;


            while( apuntadorAuxiliar -> sig != NULL)
                    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar -> sig;
    }
return 0;
}


void imprimirLista(_nodo *apuntador){
    _nodo *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    printf("Contenido de la lista: inicioLista -> ");

    while(apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
    {
            printf("%d -> ", apuntadorAuxiliar -> valor);
            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar -> sig;
    }

    printf("NULL \n");

    return;
}

int main()
{
    _nodo *inicioLista;

    inicioLista = crearLista(inicioLista);

    inicioLista = insertarEnLista(5, inicioLista);
    imprimirLista(inicioLista);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_nodo *inicioLista = NULL;
```

Change the definition to this, it will work